# How do I pass a variable into a JS while loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I want to recursively sum an integer: to split an integer into an array and then sum the individual items until I am left with a single integer array.

This is my logic:

1. Take an integer (n) and split it into an array.
2. Sum all the individual numbers.
3. Is the number greater than 9?

   1. YES: Repeat steps 1 and 2
   2. NO: Return the number

```
function digital_root(n) {
  let digits = (""+n).split("").map(Number);
  while (digits.length > 1) {
    let result = digits.reduce((sum, int) => sum + int);
    let digits = (""+result).split("").map(Number);
  }
  return digits;
};
```

This is the error code my Node.js chucks at me (at line 4 in the example code above):

```
ReferenceError: digits is not defined
    at digital_root (repl:6:18)
```

I'm assuming that the variable `digits` is accessible inside the scope of the while loop, but obviously, I seem to be wrong? Could someone shed some insight here for me, please?

---

EDIT: Thank you everyone for your help! I've solved the issue.
For your curiosity, this is the mathematical form underlying my algorithm:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigitalRoot.html

It could also have been solved in one line:

```
function digital_root(n) {
  return (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
}
```

Comment: It probably means that `digits` doesn't have a value. Do `console.log(digits)` right before the while loop

Comment: the variable is accessible within the function I've checked. It's only within the while loop that it isn't accessible.

Comment: remove the let inside your loop. you're defining it twice.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set `digits` in that manner, the `digits` inside of the loop should not have `let` in front of it because you have already defined `digits` outside the loop.

This will give you the result you expect:

```js
digital_root = n => (Array.from(`${n}`)).reduce((sum, val) => sum + ~~val, 0);


console.log(digital_root(12345));
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

The inner let for digits (line 5) should be removed

```
function digital_root(n) {
  let digits = (""+n).split("").map(Number);
  while (digits.length > 1) {
    let result = digits.reduce((sum, int) => sum + int);
    digits = (""+result).split("").map(Number);
  }
  return digits;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is let keyword, as **let** has block level scope, "digits" is not defined at the start of the while loop

Removing let for digits in while loop

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  let digits = (""+n).split("").map(Number);
  while (digits.length > 1) {
    let result = digits.reduce((sum, int) => sum + int);
    digits = (""+result).split("").map(Number);
  }
  return digits;
}

console.log(digital_root(47))
```